# How to put div over canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

There is canvas tag. I have Menu with sub menu on that canvas. When user click on `Setting`, sub menu was showed. Sub menu was show over canvas but if i click on sub menu calling canvas click event.

```
<div id="canvas">
    <ul class="toolBarul" id="toolBar">
        <li class="toolBarli">
            <a class="button" onclick="toggleSetting()">Setting</a>
            <ul id="SettingWrap">
               <li><input id="rainControl" type="checkbox" onchange="rainControl(this)"><label>rain<span class="chktoc"></span></label></li>
               <li><input id="flameControl" type="checkbox" onchange="flameControl(this)" checked="checked"><label>flame<span class="chktoc"></span></label></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="toolBarli" style="float: right;padding: 4px;">
            <img src="images/Logo.png" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

#SettingWrap{
    display:none;
    width: 280px;
    height:308px;
    top: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 598;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 40, 58, 0.91);
    padding: 5px;
}

#SettingWrap li {
    width: 267px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #9dd702;
}
```

According to [this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1903884&seqNum=8), i write below code but don't work:

```
$("#SettingWrap").on("mousedown", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[image]

Comment: So why it in the `#canvas` div? Can't you move it out?

Comment: I was added picture to my question. I want something like this. I move i out of #canvas but it don't solve problem

Comment: Your question really has nothing to do with WebGL or three.js. It's a standard HTML/CSS/JavaScript question of which there are likely 1000+ answers already on SO. If you're that unfamiliar with HTML/CSS/JavaScript I'd suggest you go read some tutorials. SO is not really the place to *start* learning.

Comment: Has nothing to do with "canvas" element too... I guess down to interpretation... use bootstrap, will solve you time and time == money.

Comment: Let me see if I understand, when you, for example, check the `sun` checkbox, the `click` event on the canvas fired too?

Comment: @Mosh Feu, Yes. When i click any where of `li`, the click event on the canvas fired too.

Comment: @Tez Wingfield, just put link of bootstrap on page?

Comment: @Farzaneh bootstrap, well is a "bootstrapper"... Most new projects created in VS use bootstrap, it allows you to focus more on the business logic rather the nuances of html/css structuring. Please search for Bootstrap or nuget... reference in your master/layout... use "Nav" css and your good to go, requires a very small learning curve to build the nav you want.

Comment: I'm not sure that bootstrap will solve it because it seems that someone is "listen" to document `click` and calculate  if the click is "in" the `canvas` so my suggestion is to call [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) after the link `click`.

Comment: The article you linked says: "To combine other HTML controls with your canvases, you may first be inclined to embed those controls inside your canvas elements, but that won’t work ... you must place your controls outside of your canvas elements."

Comment: I dont see `<canvas>` tag I see just div with id names canvas

Comment: @Mosh Feu, Thank you, I use `event.stopPropagation()` and put it before `click` event of canvas and my problem solved.

Comment: My pleasure :) Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mosh Feu said in comments, I call `event.stopPropagation()` before `click` event of canvas and it solved my problem.